# Userform opens new workbook but is behind old workbook on screen

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook lets call it workbook A with different buttons on it. One of the buttons launches a UserForm to ask the user for some information to be inputted into a separate workbook. After the user clicks OK if open up workbook B and inputs the data. The problem is the user has to minimize workbook A to start working on workbook B.

I have tried

```
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
```

and also

```
Windows("MyWorkbook").Visible = False
```

These make the window disappear completely. I just want to minimize the window. I have also tried recording what happens when you minimize but nothing is recorded for minimizing a window. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
```

or

```
ActiveWindow.WindowState = 1
```

Comment: No prob! glad to help c: